# Python: Interrupting sender with incoming messages

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, event-handling

I'm working with socket, asynchronous event-driven programming. I would like to send a message, once I receive a response, send another message. But I may be doing something besides listening. That is, I want to get interrupted when socket.recv() actually receives a message.

Question 1: How can I let layer 3 interrupt layer 4? i.e. How can I handle the event of a non-null returning socket.recv() without actually dedicating "program time" to actually wait for a specific time to listen to incoming messages?

Comment: Do you use any libraries? I would recommend select (you can handle all sockets at a time) or maybe twisted. Or else you can `sock.settimeout(0)` to return immediately when recv-ing.

Answer (score 0):

In asynchronous programming you don't interrupt an operation triggered by a message. All operations should be done in a short and fast fashion so you can process lots of messages per second. This way every operation is atomic and you don't suffer any race conditions so easily.
If you are in need to do more complex processing in parallel you could hand those problems over to a helper thread. Libraries like twisted are prepared for such use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use sockets directly? I would otherwise recommend looking into the excellent [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) library for python. It handles all the async work for you, so you can focus on writing handlers and other logic your code needs. Twisted is relatively easy to get started with. Take a look at some examples at http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/index.html.